# Random Walk v Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, random-walk

Is there a way to tell if a sequence of random numbers comes from a 'random walk' or a from a random sample from a distribution?  In other words, suppose I generate 1000 values using the usual random walk formula [xi+1 = xi + RANDOMNORMAL value].  OR I select 1000 values using a typical Normal Random Number Generator.  Can I distinguish one sequence as a random walk and the other as coming from a distribution, without knowing anything about how the random walk steps were generated OR what distribution function was used for the sample of random numbers?

Comment: You could look at the empirical distribution and see which distribution it fits the best.

Comment: That might be able to fit an arbitrary distribution, using one of the many distribution fitting programs.  Some distributions are so general that they can be fit to virtually any sequence, such as a Weibull.  But then you depend on the stats for the fit.  But I am not sure that this approach actually distinguishes that the data is truly a random walk, and not a distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly speaking, a random walk will have much higher correlations between close by times than an iid sequence. In particular, you can consider $X_n$ given by sampling from a Brownian motion at integer times, vs. an iid sequence $Y_n$ of $N(0,1)$ random variables. In the latter case, $E[Y_m Y_n]=0$ for $m \neq n$. In the former case, $E[X_m X_n]=\min \{ m,n \}$. If all you have is one trajectory then technically you cannot robustly say anything about statistics. Nevertheless, if you plot the autocorrelation with some fixed window, for example if you plot $X_n X_{n+r}$ and $Y_n Y_{n+r}$ for some fixed positive integer $r$, you should find that the former oscillates around zero while the latter fluctuates but generally drifts upward.

Comment: A simple lag of 1 creates a near perfect correlation between the lagged values from a random walk.  Even for biased random walks. 
 Random numbers from a distribution have no correlations.  One example of a dataset has been that the stock market is a random walk.  Applying above produces a similar result for a random walk.  It appears that the correlation (lag -1) being near perfect for stock market data would seem to resolve the issue that indeed the stock market is a random walk, implying no prediction.  Would this be your observation?